# Вывести метод из другого класса opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart

Подскажите как вывести метод из `system/library` оба файла лежат в одной папке `library`

```
$customer = new Customer('library/customer');

$sub = $customer->getFirstName();

print_r($sub);
```

но почему то выдает ошибку

Comment: дополнил свой ответ, проверяйте

Comment: Ну и какую ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

В OpenCart иначе это делается, там не нужно объявлять объект `$customer = new Customer('library/customer');` Тем более вы пытаетесь в конструктор класса Customer передать просто строку, хотя он требует объект $registry.

Достаточно использовать

```
$sub = $this->customer->getFirstName();
print_r($sub);
```

**Исходя из комментариев дополню свой ответ:**

Вы пытаетесь из класса Url вызвать класс Customer. Конструктор класса Customer требует объект $registry, которого нет в классе Url. Тем не менее это можно реализовать следующим образом:

Добавить приватное свойство $registry для класса Url (в начале класса пропишите `public $registry;`)
Добавить в конструктор `__contruct` дополнительный код, чтобы он выглядел так:

```
public function __construct($url, $ssl = '', $registry) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->ssl = $ssl;
        $this->registry = $registry; 
    }
```

Немного меняем файл `/system/framework.php`, находим строку сеттера Url, она выглядит примерно так:

```
// Url
if ($config->get('url_autostart')) {
    $registry->set('url', new Url($config->get('site_base'), $config->get('site_ssl')));
}
```

и добавляем в вызов Url тот самый $registry

```
// Url
if ($config->get('url_autostart')) {
    $registry->set('url', new Url($config->get('site_base'), $config->get('site_ssl'), $registry));
}
```

Теперь класс Url содержит нужный объект, осталось только правильно вызвать класс `Customer`

Вызывать его нужно добавляя в его конструктор `$this->registry`, то есть код будет выглядеть так

```
$customer = new Customer($this->registry);
$sub = $customer->getFirstName();
print_r($sub);
```

**Однако!** Нахрена это нужно делать я не понимаю.

Comment: я хочу вызвать этот метод в классе Url  если так вызывать то выдает ошибку Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstName() on null

Comment: @Sender1050 Конструктор customer требует объект $registry, который содержит текущую сессию, базу, конфиг и т.д. Из класса Url вы не можете вызвать Customer, так как у этого класса в принципе нет таких данных

Answer (score 1):

В документации же есть: http://docs.opencart.com/developer/loading/

Т.е по сути: `$this->load->library`

Comment: url видает ошибку